# Move elements down as p tags approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is basically  a chat layout and I want the button and input elements to automatically move down as the messaging approaches.
But when I try to do this, the elements don't move down, they only remain there where they are.

I expect that the input and the button tags move downward as the messages approach.

jQuery accepted.

```js
var p = document.createElement('p');
var message = document.querySelector('#messages');
var button = document.querySelector('#typeb');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p = document.createElement('p');
  p.setAttribute('id', 'user');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('This is a message sent.');
  p.appendChild(txt);
  message.appendChild(p);
  reply();
});

function reply() {
  p = document.createElement('p');
  p.setAttribute('id', 'sent');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('This is a message sent. jwejfhwewfwwef \n Hello Priyal');
  p.appendChild(txt);
  message.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#typer {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(50%, 100vh);
}

#typeb {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(160%, 100vh);
}

#user {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 40px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
}

#sent {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="messages">
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="typer">
  <button id="typeb">Say it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry about that but the code is kinda huge.

Comment: This is why you should create a [mcve] and not provide [too much code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Comment: I'm somewhat new to Stack OverFlow and I don't know all the rules(still)

Comment: I voted to reopen

Comment: You do not want to go off topic which means not ON topic which is a good thing. You want your question to be re-opened. Perhaps it will be soon. No need to beg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7npghLsj/

Comment: just need something for the lines (they poison the ui)? how do i make them invisible? (color: white;) does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var p = document.createElement('p');
var message = document.querySelector('#messages');
var button = document.querySelector('#typeb');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p = document.createElement('p');
  p.setAttribute('id', 'user');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('This is a message sent.');
  p.appendChild(txt);
  message.appendChild(p);
  reply();
});

function reply() {
  p = document.createElement('p');
  p.setAttribute('id', 'sent');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('This is a message sent. jwejfhwewfwwef \n Hello Priyal');
  p.appendChild(txt);
  message.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#typer {
  position: fixed;
   bottom:0;
}

#typeb {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
}

#user {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 40px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
}

#sent {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="messages">
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="typer">
  <button id="typeb">Say it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I expected it to slide with the messages